# CASE clause for this relation, testing aggregate functions over another relation

Tags: sql, switch-statement, aggregate-functions

How can I represent a single value in a query, based on testing several possible results from the aggregate of another relation in the join?

I have a database with this schema:

```
TABLE lorem (
    id INTEGER
    name VARCHAR
    created TIME STAMP
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLE ipsum (
    id INTEGER
    lorem_id INTEGER
        REFERENCES lorem(id)
    state VARCHAR
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This is currently accessed via Django models:

```python
class Lorem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    def state(self):
        ipsum_states = [ipsum.state for ipsum in self.ipsum_set]

        if ipsum_states and all(
                ipsum_state == 'complete' for ipsum_state in ipsum_states):
            state = 'done'
        elif any(
                ipsum_state == 'error' for ipsum_state in ipsum_states):
            state = 'failure'
        elif any(
                ipsum_state == 'begin' for ipsum_state in ipsum_states):
            state = 'sending'
        else:
            state = 'not started'

        return state

class Ipsum(models.Model):
    lorem = models.ForeignKey(Lorem)
    state = models.CharField()
```

That works correctly in Python. But it's too slow to calculate for every instance.

Now I need to translate the per-Lorem-instance conditions and aggregations above, to whole-set aggregations in a SELECT statement.

So I want to have the `state` value determined in a database view:

```sql
SELECT
    lorem.name AS name,
    CASE
        WHEN [… all the ipsum.state values,
            for the set of ipsum referring to this lorem,
            are 'complete' …] THEN 'done'
        WHEN [… any ipsum.state value,
            for the set of ipsum referring to this lorem,
            is 'error' …] THEN 'failure'
        WHEN [… any ipsum.state value,
            for the set of ipsum referring to this lorem,
            is 'begin' …] THEN 'sending'
        ELSE 'not started'
    END AS state
FROM
    lorem
    LEFT INNER JOIN ipsum
        ON ipsum.lorem_id = lorem.id
;
```

How can I construct that CASE clause so that the aggregate functions, on *one* `Lorem` instance used in the Python code, will do the appropriate set operations **per instance of `lorem`** in the SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE ipsum.states 
  WHEN 'complete' THEN 'done' 
  WHEN 'error' THEN 'failure'  
  WHEN 'begin' THEN 'sending' 
  ELSE 'not started' 
END as state
```

Comment: The `ipsum` relation does not have a `states` field. The point is to do several different *aggregations of* the `state` field on all of the related `ipsum` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your database looks as follows:

Table1 
lorem_name ,lorem_id, ipsum_state

Table2:
lorem_id

What you essentially need is a flag to work on from the first case when and an aggregation in the outer query which has another case when. SQL works row by row and hence an outer query is required.

```
SELECT name,
case 
when min(state)=1 then 'done'
when min(state)=-1 then 'error'
when min(state)=0 then 'sending'
when min(state)=-2 then 'not started'
from
(
    SELECT
    lorem.name AS name,
    CASE
    WHEN ipsum.state=='complete' then 1 
    WHEN ipsum.state=='error' then -1
    WHEN ipsum.state='begin' then 0
    ELSE '-2'
    END AS state
    FROM
    lorem
    LEFT INNER JOIN ipsum
    ON ipsum.lorem_id = lorem.id
)group by 1;
```

Hope this solves your problem. (Please ignore the bad indentation)

Comment: There's no need for nesting, you can simply use a Valued Case: `case min(CASE WHEN ipsum.state...) when 1...`

Comment: Very cool. I feel computationally though , both the queries would run at the same speed. I am not a big fan of nested queries as it increases difficulty in code readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
    WHEN [… all the ipsum.states are 'complete' …] THEN 'done'
    WHEN [… any of the ipsum.states are 'error' …] THEN 'failure'
    WHEN [… any of the ipsum.states are 'begin' …] THEN 'sending'
    ELSE 'not started'
END AS state
```

Can be written as

```
CASE
   WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ipsum.states = 'complete' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*) THEN 'done'
   WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ipsum.states = 'error'    THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'failure'
   WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ipsum.states = 'begin'    THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'sending'
   ELSE 'not started'
END AS state
```

It is a pretty literate translation of your pseudocode: Note that `count` does not count `null` values; the default `else` part of `case` is `else null`. That means, each `case` inside the `count` only counts those rows matching the criteria. This count is compared to the total count (for the "all" case) or just `>1` for the "any" case.

Here is an article I wrote about this concept:
- http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Comment: There is no `ipsum.states` field; that was a pseudo-placeholder for what I don't know how to write. I have updated the question to avoid the impression that is a field.